# Any reason not to prefix Java type parameters with a dollar sign?

Tags: java, generics, naming-conventions

First off, I know not to use dollar signs in class names, because inner classes get dollar signs in their .class file names. I've also seen synthetic variable names like `this$0`, so I tend to avoid dollar signs in identifiers like any good Java programmer.

However, I find single-letter type parameters like `<T>` to be repugnant. If I'm making a generic class that has parameters for requests and responses, for instance, I have a naming problem. What should I use, `<TRequest, TResponse>`? `<R1, R2>`? Gross.

I've started doing `<$Request, $Response>`. It's readable, it's distinct, and I can't imagine any .class file naming conflicts. Seems to me like low-hanging fruit for making Java code more readable. Any JVM gurus or insightful devs want to tell me why this is a terrible idea?

**Edit:** As for readability, I may be drawn towards this by my use of other languages in which variables are prefixed with dollar signs, and generic types are types with a more variable nature than class types. As for convention, yes, I'm a fan; I want to know whether this *would* work as a convention, or if some technical issue would prevent it.

Comment: _It's readable_ No, I don't think so.

Comment: Stick with what helps others and your future self be able to better understand your code. So if you're coding for school or for a business, you'll want to stick with their naming protocols whatever they may be, since uniformity in naming and formatting is key. If on the other hand you're coding just for yourself, and there is little chance that the code will be shared with others, then do what works best for you.

Answer (score 3):

## Convention, convention, convention.

Although you're free to do as you wish, the general convention can be found [in the Java Trails](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> - E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
> - K - Key
> - N - Number
> - T - Type
> - V - Value
> - S,U ,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
>
> You'll see these names used throughout the Java SE API...

Breaking these conventions should only be done when:

- Following the above protocol would make the generic *more* confusing to use
- The readability gains can be readily identified by other collaborators

Explicitly in the case of $, the JLS has a recommendation *against* [using `$` as a generic identifier.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

> The `$` sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

Comment: Unfortunately, the JLS just makes that statement and cites no source or discussion. Where would I go to learn more about this?

Comment: The JLS is regarded as the absolute source of truth about the language.  If you're looking for an opinion from the metaphorical horse's mouth, that's the best place to find it.

Comment: The "Oracle" of truth then? Heh. And no, I'm interested in learning the specifics: what problems have arisen, what problems are we likely to encounter, how might my suggestion relate to those problems. I don't get that from a footnote in the spec. I'm willing to put in the time because the current convention irks me enough.